# Whitney Conditions vs Equisingularity

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, stratifications

In studying singular spaces, it is often important to pick an appropriate stratification which encodes the singularity structure. One class of such stratifications are called "Whitney stratifications" after the work of H. Whitney (with many following contributions by Thom, Mather..) . A Whitney stratification obeys certain conditions that are meant to intuitively capture the idea that every point on a fixed stratum looks roughly the same.

Now, there appears to be a somewhat separate theory of "equisingularity" due to O. Zariski . My question is :

- How closely are these two theories related ? In particular, is it possible to have an "equisingular stratification" (I am not sure if this the right technical term) that is *not* a Whitney stratification ?

I have seen weakened versions of Whitney conditions appearing at various places in the literature, but I don't know of a place where these are compared with Zariski's notion of "equisingularity".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean by "equisingular" stratification. But I guess you would like to say that *$X$ is equisingular along $Y$* if the local rings $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ have constant multiplicity for all $x \in Y$. The *equisingular stratification* would be a stratification with respect to the condition being *equisingular* along a subvariety.

In that case, equisingular stratifications and Whitney stratifications are not the same thing (though a Whitney stratification is always an equisingular stratification). You can construct a counter-example as follows.

First of all, if I remember correctly, if $Y \subset X$ is a smooth Whitney stratum, then $X$ is normally flat along $Y$. In particular, if $Y$ is closed in $X$, then the scheme-theoretic exceptional divisor of the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$ is flat over $Y$.

Now, let $Z$ be a generic hyperplane section of $\mathbb{P}^2 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \subset \mathbb{P}^5$. The surface $Z$ is a ruled cubic surface. I denote by $L$ the principal axis of the ruling.

Let us denote by $X \subset (\mathbb{P}^4)^*$ the projective dual of $Z$. It is easily checked that $X$ is a cubic hypersurface which is not a cone. In particular, all singular points of $X$ have exactly multiplicty $2$ in $X$.

Let $H$ be a hyperplane containing $L$. Since $H$ cuts $Z$ in a curve of degree $3$ (Bezout's Theorem), we have $H \cap Z = L \cup \mathcal{C}$, were $\mathcal{C}$ is a curve of degree $2$ on $Z$. In fact, one proves easily that $\mathcal{C}$ must be the union of two lines ruling $Z$, say $l_H$ and $l'_H$.

If $l_H \neq l'_H$, then $H$ is tangent to $Z$ along the two points $l_H \cap L$ and $l'_H \cap L$. Thus, $H^{\perp}$ is a singular point of $X$ and the tangency locus of $H$ along $Z$ is two distinct points.

If $l_H = l'_H$, then $H$ is tangent to $Z$ along $l_H$. Again $H$ is a singular point of $X$.

This shows that $L^{\perp}$ is in the singular locus of $X$. In fact, one proves that the singular locus of $X$ is exactly $L^{\perp}$. Hence, the singular locus of $X$ is a $\mathbb{P}^2$ (in particular it is smooth) and $X$ has multiplicity exactly $2$ along all the points of $H^{\perp}$. Hence $X - L^{\perp} ; L^{\perp}$ is an equi-singular stratification of $X$.

Let me prove that this stratification is not a Whitney stratification. By the preliminary remark, I only have to prove that $X$ is not normally flat along $L^{\perp}$.

Let $I_Z =\{(z,H^{\perp}) \in Z \times (\mathbb{P}^{N})^*, \textrm{such that} \, T_{Z,z} \subset H \}$ be the conormal variety of $Z$. Its projection on the second factor maps onto the projective dual of $Z$ (which is $X$).

If $Z$ is smooth and its projective dual is a hypersurface, it is a classical result of Nash that $I_Z$ is the blow-up of $X$ along its singular locus (which is $L^{\perp}$).

As a consequence, we see that the exceptional locus of this blow-up can not be flat over $L^{\perp}$. Indeed, if $p$ is the projection:

$$ p : I_Z \longrightarrow X$$

then the fiber of $p$ over $H^{\perp} \in L^{\perp}$ is:

_ two points when $l_H \neq l'_H$

_a line when $l_H = l'_H$.

This proves that $X$ is not normally flat along $L^{\perp}$ and so $X-L^{\perp}, L^{\perp}$ is not a Whitney stratification of $X$.

**Hope for Whitney = equisingular**. Teissier and his collaborators introduced in the 70's a much finer notion of multiplicity (which basically takes into account all the
multiplicities of the local rings of all the generic polars passing through a fixed point of $X$) and he proves in that context that Whitney = equisingular.
The paper where he proves this result is called "Variétés polaires II : Mulitplicités polaires, sections planes et conditions de Whitney". You can find it here : https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernard.teissier/documents/VarPol2.pdf

Comment: My terminology was indeed imprecise. I think you have given one precise version of what can be termed a equisingular stratification. As for whether Whitney implies $X$ should be normally flat along $L^{\perp}$ (in your example), I am not sure. Would failure of this lead to a failure of just Whitney condition B or will it lead to failure of both Whitney conditions A and B ?  (failure of Whitney condition A would automatically mean the failure of condition B)

Comment: @Aswin : I am almost entirely sure that Whitney implies normally flat. The result of Trotman quoted by Liviu Nicolaescu below is a $\mathcal{C}^1$ version of this. The normal cone and the normal link are somehow the same thing. 

I do not remember which of Whitney conditions is violated by the failure of normal flatness. Looking at the result of Trotman, I would say condition $b$, but not for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a result of Trotman relevant  to your question. $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $\newcommand{\ra}{\rightarrow}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\cl}{cl}$ $\DeclareMathOperator{\dist}{dist}$

> Suppose that  $(X,Y)$  is a pair of $C^1$ submanifolds  of  the $\bR^N$, $\dim X= m$.   Assume $X\subset\cl(Y)\setminus Y$.  Then the pair $(X,Y)$ satisfies the Whitney regularity   condition (b) along $X$ if and only  if, for any  open  set  $U\subset \bR^N$, and any    $C^1$-diffeomorphism  $\Psi :  U\ra V$, where $V$ is an open subset of $\bR^N$, such that
>   $$
> \Psi(U\cap X) \subset \bR^m\oplus 0 \subset \bR^N,
> $$
>   the map
>   $$
>  \Psi(Y\cap U)\ra \bR^m\times (0,\infty),\;\;y\longmapsto \bigl( \,{\rm proj}\,(y)\,, \,\dist(y,\bR^m)^2\,\bigr),
>  $$
>    is a submersion, where ${\rm proj}:\bR^N\ra \bR^m$ denotes the canonical orthogonal projection

The submersion condition is a form of equisingularity. The fiber of the above submersion is the normal link of $X$ in $Y$. For details see D. Trotman's original paper

> *Geometric versions of Whitney regularity conditions*, Ann. Scien. Ec. Norm. Sup., ´ 4(1979), 453-463.

Comment: In this case, I think the first Whitney condition (usually called condition $A$) is still obeyed.. right ?  In general, does the condition of equisingularity require that atleast the first Whitney be obeyed or is even this not a necessary requirement ?

Comment: It is known that B implies A.     Condition A  does not guarantee  equisingularity The Whintey cusp $y^2+x^3-x^2z^2=0$ satisfies $A$ along the $z$ axis, but not $B$.

Comment: Yes, I am aware that B => A for Whitney conditions. I was asking a question about equisingular stratifications that are not Whitney. Do these stratifications obey condition A or do they not even obey that ?

Comment: Heres a bit of history. Initially Whitney believed that A guarantees  equisingularity. He then  observed that  the Whitney cusp     with an obvious stratification satisfies A yet it is not equisingular. That is   when he improved A to B.  I suggest you  have of look at  Section 4.2 of the notes  http://www3.nd.edu/~lnicolae/Morse2nd.pdf  It is a rather informal introduction to  Whitney stratifications with  pictures,  examples  and a discussion of equisingularity that might  address some of your questions. It also contains references I found useful.

Comment: Those are some very nice notes and a fantastic introduction to the Whitney theory!  But, unless I have misunderstood your answer and comments.. these are in a slightly different direction from my question.  I believe Zariski's definition of equisingularity is in general different from the one Whitney obtained using his two conditions (the other answer by Libli + ref to Tessier's works seems to also indicate this).

Comment: (..condt...) My question was really about understanding how far away  Zariski's notion of equisingularity is from Whitney's notion.  I am not questioning the fact that to retrieve Whitney's notion of equisingularity.. one needs both conditions A and B.  I find Whitney's conditions very intuitive and I would be quite happy if I never have to think of another notion equisingularity .. but I ran into the term "equisingular" in some situations where there was no Whitney stratification. So, I wanted to be sure how exactly Zariski's theory diverged from Whitney's theory ..

Comment: I have to admit that I am not very fluent in algebraic geometry, but  geometrically the notions of  equisingularity should be, in spirit, very similar.  I am aware  that  "in spirit" is not the answer you're looking for.  I don't think Whitney's condition  has  an exact counterpart in algebraic geometry since it involves metric notions which are far removed from Zariski type topologies. I would look for  definitions that have the attributes "local" and "flat" in them.