# The relative dimension of blow-up and singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, blow-ups

Let $X$ be an integral affine scheme of finite type over $\mathbb{C}$, $\mathrm{dim}\,X=d$. Let $Y\subset  X$ be an integral closed subscheme of codimension $n>0$. We blow up $X$ along $Y$ and get a scheme $Bl_Y X$. Let $m_X(Y)$ be the maximum dimension of a closed subscheme of $Bl_YX$ that is proper (as a $\mathbb{C}$-scheme).

- if we fix $X$, and vary $Y$, is it true that $m_X(Y)$ has a uniform upper bound? Since $X$ is of finite type, I would think that this should be true.
- if we fix only $d$, and let $X$ and $Y$ vary, is it true that $m_X(Y)$ has a uniform upper bound?
- if we fix only $n$, and let $X$ and $Y$ vary, is it true that $m_X(Y)$ has a uniform upper bound?
- the above question under the assumption that $X$ is smooth/under the assumption that $Y$ is smooth;
- more generally, what does the dimension of the fibers of blow-up say about the singularities of the locus that is being blown-up?

Answer (score 2):

For the first four questions, are you just asking what is the maximal dimension of a fiber of the blow-up map : $p : \mathrm{Bl}_{Y}(X) \longrightarrow X$? If that is the case, then for $X$ and $Y$ integral, the maximum of dimension of a fiber is $\dim X -1$ and it is attained when you blow-up a point in $X$.

The last question can be made into an interesting question if you transform it slightly. The dimension of the fibers can be arbitrary between $0$ and $d-1$, whatever the type of singularities, so nothing's interesting there. On the other hand, you could ask what is the relation between the **variation** of dimensions of the fibers of the blow-up along $Y$ and the **variation** of singularities of $X$ along $Y$.

This topic was studied a lot in the 60's, mostly in connection with Hironaka resolution's of singularities. Namely, Hironoka says that $X$ is *normally flat* along $Y$ if the exceptionnal divisor of the blow-up of $X$ along $Y$ is flat over $Y$. In particular, all fibers of the blow-up have the same dimension over points of $Y$. In case $Y$ is smooth, normal flatness is a notion of equi-singularity in a very strong sense. You can have a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263752/whitney-conditions-vs-equisingularity/263758#263758). It implies that all points of $Y$ have the same multiplicity in $X$, but in general it implies much more : namely that all generic polars varieties with respect to $X$ which contain $Y$ have the same multiplicity along $Y$ (this is a [hard Theorem of Teissier](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~bernard.teissier/documents/Cargese.pdf)).

Let me restrict to a simple case where things can be easily can be computed : assume that $X$ is a divisor in a smooth variety. If $Y$ is a smooth subvariety of $X$, then $X$ is **normally flat** along $Y$ if and only if all points of $Y$ have the **same multiplicity** in $X$. This computation in the case of hypersurfaces in ambient smooth varieties has been first carried out by Hironaka himself, but I think that Lejeune-Jalabert and Teissier gave a [simpler approach](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01053223) to this result.

Very recently, this notion of normal flatness has proved to be quite useful in the context of non-commutative resolutions of singularities.

**EDIT** (22/04/19) : The answer to question 3 is no. Indeed let $\mathcal{N}_n$ be the nilpotent cone for $\mathrm{SL}_n$. The springer resolution:
$$ \mu :  T^* \left(\mathrm{SL_n}/B \right) \longrightarrow \mathcal{N}_n$$ is birational (a resolution of singularities) and for any $x \in \mathcal{O}_{subreg}$ , we have $\dim \mu^{-1}(x) \geq 1$ (where $\mathcal{O}_{subreg}$ is the subregular orbit). Since $\mathrm{codim}(\mathcal{O}_{subreg} \subset \mathcal{N}_n) = 2$, we deduce that the Richardson map is the blow-up along a subvariety of codimension $2$.

Finally the fiber of $\mu$ over $0$ is the complete flag varieties of $\mathrm{SL}_n$, it has dimension $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: @AknazarKazhymurat : apparently, you don't understand the example in the answer you have linked. The scheme that is blown-up there has codimension $2$ in the ambient variety that has dimension $4$.

Comment: @Libli so do you know the answer to the 3rd question?